# How to include Meta Keywords and Meta Description in Sitecore Lucene search index?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, sitecore, meta-tags

I have a Lucene search working great on an existing Sitecore website, but recently I discovered the Meta tags don't seem to be included in the indexes.  This is not a major issue, but I am curious to know if there is a way to tell Lucene to include the Meta Description and Keywords content in its indexes.  Being a Sitecore website, my index definitions are set up in my web.config file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste your current index definition(s) from the web.config into the question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene only indexes the fields in your data templates. (It doesn't crawl your site)  So if you want Lucene to index Meta Keywords and Meta Description then you need to make sure that your data templates have fields for both of those and then you have to set up your index in web.config to include those fields.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have the meta data exposed as fields in my data templates, so it must just be a matter of properly reconfiguring my index definitions in web.config. Thanks for the info!